# How to synchronize a collection of values in C#

Tags: c#, synchronization

I have inherited some code that has a set of real-time values that are captured over a serial link that runs on a separate thread:

```
class Data
{
    public static int nFooCount;
    public static decimal meanValue;
    // Lots more of a variety of types.
}
```

The thread just stores the data into the field with no locking or other synchronization. Looks like a whole sea of race conditions to me. So I want to add some safety to it. The question is, what's best?

I could make the int fields volatile. Can't do that with the decimal types, though. Interlocked can help with that, albeit messily, using boxing. Or I could add a lock object

```
private static readonly object lockObj = new object();
```

and then accessor everything. But this locks all the fields even when it will only modify one at a time. I can't lock on primitives and that would be bad form anyway, and adding a lock object for every field would look wasteful. So is there a better way?

Comment: You write "on a separate thread". That is singular. To me it sounds as if only one thread is writing these values. If that really is the case there are no race conditions there, hence no locking is required.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth if the writer thread has a non-atomic write, the reader thread could read invalid data.

Comment: Daniel - What happens if the main thread is pre-empted and attempts a read whilst the IO thread has only half written the field?

Comment: Indeed, that could happen, haven't thought about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could lock according to required access level using [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx). You could do this better by turning them into a property:

```
public int Something
{
   get {
      locker.EnterReadLock();

      try {
         return something;
      } finally {
         locker.ExitReadLock();
      }
   }
   set {
      locker.EnterWriteLock();

      try {
         something = value;
      } finally {
         locker.ExitWriteLock();
      }
   }
}
```

This allows for multiple reads and single writes.

Comment: That's not bad. I use a single locker for all the fields in the class, not a locker PER field in the class, yes?

Comment: Yes a single locker for all fields usually.